# Bullet tips and tricks

Tags: strategy, tactics, computer-chess, time-management, bullet-chess

Nowadays with speedy Internet and in order to play lots of opponents and to decrease the chance of cheating, people are opting for Bullet or blitz.

Generally I prefer to play Larsen opening or Double fianchetto or sometimes Ruy lopez. The traps in these openings are not in the openings but in the captures ( capturing the pawns or Knight with bishops). If the opponent is careless and pre- moves then these tricks work.

But many of the players are unaware of these things and many other gambits or trick.

If you are a pro player of bullet games what bullet-specific tricks do you use?

Comment: I am intrigued by your mention of specific openings for bullet. Perhaps you could add an answer giving details?

Answer (score 2):

These tricks work much better in bullet, where flagging is probably 50% of the game, than in blitz.

The obvious one is to reply to the start of a fianchetto by threatening the square the bishop is about to move to in case it was pre-moved. e.g. reply to g3 with Bh3. Of course if your opponent didn't pre-move and your bishop is unprotected then you lose a piece but you should only do this when your opponent is playing some opening with minimal contact and with automatic moves like for instance the Kings Indian Attack with white.